# Как заставить работа style в js скрипте на Python'e

Tags: javascript, html, css, python

Есть код

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main.css' %}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function foo(n) {
        element = document.getElementById('n')
        if (element.style.display == 'none')
            element.style.display = 'block'
        else element.style.display = 'none';
    }
    </script>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="accesses">
        <form id="accessForm" action="access/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Title" name="title">
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Service" name="service">
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Login" name="login">
            <input type="password" required placeholder="Password" 
             name="password">
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Comment" name="comment">
            <input type="text" required placeholder="Owner" name="owner">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Add access">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="showAccesses">
        <h3>Accesses</h3>
        <div class="showServices">
            {% for access in Accesses %}
                <a href="#" onclick="foo({{ access.login }})">{{ access.service }}</a>
                <div style="display: none" id="{{ access.login }}">
                    <p id="moreInfo">{{ access.title }}</p>
                    <p id="moreInfo">{{ access.login }}</p>
                    <p id="moreInfo">{{ access.password }}</p>
                    <p id="moreInfo">{{ access.comment }}</p>
                    <p id="moreInfo">{{ access.owner }}</p>
                </div>
                <hr>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Я читал на форумах о том, что стили "мигающих" элементов js не ловит.
Как мне сделать, чтобы он начал видеть style property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element = document.getElementById('n')
```

Поменяй на

```
element = document.getElementById(n)
```

Comment: Ещё раз убеждаюсь в том, что всё держится на мелочах. Спасибо большое